# Search in multidimensional array

Tags: php, opencart

On my website I have a list of products generated through a `foreach` and creates a multidimensional array.

The array is this: (Short)
http://k44.kn3.net/73194E0F9.jpg

I need to search within this multidimensional array if the value of `["model"]` repeats.

In short, I do not want to display 2 products with the same `["model"]`

Array define:

```
foreach ($results as $result) {
    $this->data['products'][] = array(
                        'product_id'  => $result['product_id'],
                        'model'    => $corto,
                        'thumb'       => $image,
                        'Disponibilidad'   => $rstock,
                        'name'        => $nombre,
                        'description' => utf8_substr(strip_tags(html_entity_decode($result['description'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8')), 0, 100) . '..',
                        'price'       => $price,
                        'special'     => $special,
                        'tax'         => $tax,
                        'rating'      => $result['rating'],
                        'reviews'     => sprintf($this->language->get('text_reviews'), (int)$result['reviews']),
                        'href'        => $this->url->link('product/product', 'path=' . $this->request->get['path'] . '&product_id=' . $result['product_id'])
                        );
}
```

Comment: 403 Forbidden - check image

Comment: @mleko works fine here.

Comment: Show us the code, not an image of it. Also post what you've tried so far.

Answer (score 1):

Not perfectly clean, but easy and fast without use of any functions. Use `model` as table key

```
$this->data['products'][$result['model']] = array(
                        'product_id'  => $result['product_id'],
```

Later you can reindex array with `array_values`

Answer (score 1):

Array of products is the variable products. Untested but should work:

```
$products // Your product array here
$models = array();
$count = 0;
foreach ($products as $product) {
    // If Model Already exits (unset / remove from array)
    if (in_array($product['model'], $models)) unset($products[$count]);
    // Add Model Number to Array
    array_push($models, $product['model']);
    // Increase Count
    $count++;
}
```

Keeps an array of models added and if already added unset.

**Updated to your updated code:**

```
$models = array();
foreach ($results as $result) {

    // Check if Model exits
     if (in_array($corto, $models)) continue;

    $this->data['products'][] = array(
        'product_id'  => $result['product_id'],
        'model'    => $corto,
        'thumb'       => $image,
        'Disponibilidad'   => $rstock,
        'name'        => $nombre,
        'description' => utf8_substr(strip_tags(html_entity_decode($result['description'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8')), 0, 100) . '..',
        'price'       => $price,
        'special'     => $special,
        'tax'         => $tax,
        'rating'      => $result['rating'],
        'reviews'     => sprintf($this->language->get('text_reviews'), (int)$result['reviews']),
        'href'        => $this->url->link('product/product', 'path=' . $this->request->get['path'] . '&product_id=' . $result['product_id'])
    );

    // Add Model to array
    array_push($models, $corto);

}
```

**Update to improve performance by Ryan:**

```
   $models = array();
foreach ($results as $result) {

    // Check if Model exits
     if (isset($models[$corto])) continue;

    $this->data['products'][] = array(
        'product_id'  => $result['product_id'],
        'model'    => $corto,
         .....
        'href'        => $this->url->link('product/product', 'path=' . $this->request->get['path'] . '&product_id=' . $result['product_id'])
    );

    // Add Model to array
    $models[$corto] = true;

}
```

Comment: do not use 'in_array' as it will be slow for large arrays. use the 'model' as the 'key' in your model lookup array as in: $models[ $product['model']] = true;. now use 'isset($models[<current product code>]) for the lookup test. will give constant performance even for large arrays.

Comment: If you add a reference to array element in the foreach loop then you can unset duplicates as you go,  as in: foreach ($results as &$result). This will be quick and use minimal extra memory.

Comment: I don't know if he want's to unset them or not

Comment: That is a good  point! perhaps just add a 'duplicate indicator' as you have the reference anyway. was fun talking with you.